# Filtrar array de datas

Tags: javascript

Bom sei que existe o `.filter()` que nele consigo filtra um array para retorna-lo apenas da forma que quero, e utilizando muito para pesquisa, quando passamos o que queremos pesquisar naquele array.

Porém estou tendo problema para filtra um array de datas como este:

```
["08:00" "09:00" "10:10" "10:30" "10:50" "11:30" "11:50" "12:00"];
```

Preciso filtra-lo por data passada tenho data inicial e data final, por exemplo passo para ele `"09:00"` e `"11:30"` ele deve retornar para mim:

```
["10:10" "10:30" "10:50"]
```

Tentando fazer isto fiz assim em meu `typescript`:

```
1. this.schedules = this.navigation.lineSelected.schedules;
2. this.schedules.filter(item => {
3.  item > this.hourNow && item < this.hourFinish
4. });
```

Na linha 1 recebo todos os horários que tenho, logo na linha 2,4 faço a filtragem deste array, porém ele me retorna ele todo.

Como posso fazer isto ?

Comment: você não precisa usar o `return` antes do:  `item > this.hourNow...` ?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui encontrar meu erro, era o `{}` então assim

```js
var array = ["08:00", "09:00", "10:10", "10:30", "10:50", "11:30", "11:50", "12:00"],
    min = "09:00",
    max = "11:30",
    result = array.filter(a => a > min && a < max);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Do jeito que você estava fazendo também é possível, bastava colocar o `return` antes da instrução.

Answer (score 1):

Perdoem-me pela grande gambiarra, mas caso ajude:

```js
var arrData = ["08:00", "09:00", "10:10", "10:30", "10:50", "11:30", "11:50", "12:00"]

var arrCondition = ["09:00", "10:30"];

var arrFinal = [];

var contador = 0;

var separaCondition1 = arrCondition[0].split(":");
var separaCondition2 = arrCondition[1].split(":");

arrData.filter(function(index){
    var separaData = index.split(":");
    if(parseInt(separaData[0]) >= parseInt( separaCondition1[0]) && parseInt(separaData[0]) <= parseInt(separaCondition2[0])){
      if(parseInt(separaData[1]) >= parseInt(separaCondition1[1]) && parseInt(separaData[1]) <= parseInt(separaCondition2[1])){
        arrFinal[contador] = separaData[0]+":"+separaData[1];
        contador++;
      }
    }
});

console.log(arrFinal);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tens de converter essas strings em valores numéricos ou datas para poder trabalhá-las.

Duas sugestões:

Convertendo em segundos

```js
function hhmmToMin(str) {
  const [h, m] = str.split(':').map(Number);
  return h * 60 + m;
}

function filtrarHoras(de, ate, arr) {
  de = hhmmToMin(de);
  ate = hhmmToMin(ate);
  return arr.filter(str => {
    const minutos = hhmmToMin(str);
    return minutos > de && minutos < ate;
  });
}

const horas = ["08:00", "09:00", "10:10", "10:30", "10:50", "11:30", "11:50", "12:00"];


const res = filtrarHoras("09:00", "11:30", horas);
console.log(res);
```

Convertendo em datas (milisegundos)

```js
function hhmmToMin(str) {
  const [h, m] = str.split(':').map(Number);
  return new Date(2010, 1, 1, h, m);
}

function filtrarHoras(de, ate, arr) {
  de = hhmmToMin(de);
  ate = hhmmToMin(ate);
  return arr.filter(str => {
    const minutos = hhmmToMin(str);
    return minutos > de && minutos < ate;
  });
}

const horas = ["08:00", "09:00", "10:10", "10:30", "10:50", "11:30", "11:50", "12:00"];


const res = filtrarHoras("09:00", "11:30", horas);
console.log(res);
```